# Yii mocking model

Tags: yii, functional-testing

I try to build a project using the Yii framework. 
Are there any possibility to mock a model object during functional tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your looking for this:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.fixture

Functional testing in Yii is stupendously simple. Create fixtures, Construct models, make assertions, Go.

Comment: Thanks. I know about fixtures. I start to develop applications with the view and controller. At this stage a model is a something very abstract and a better way to use and design it is a mock.